# Method not found when trying to re-render p:menubar in Primefaces 6.2.5 (works in 6.2.2)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm currently working on an application that uses JSF 2.2 together with Primefaces running on Wildfly 11.

Error Environment: Primefaces 6.2.5

Working environment: Primefaces 6.2.2

**Expected Behavior:**
Clicking a context menu item, should invoke a re rendering of the toolbar in the screen. This worked in previous versions.

**Actual Behavior:** 
When I click on a menu item in our screen, it will initiate a re-rendering of the toolbar. Moreover, the context menu is used as a composite component in the screen. But, the context menu item generates following error.

```
javax.el.MethodNotFoundException: /xhtml/screen/toolbar.xhtml. 
listener="#{cc.attrs.someClass.onPreRenderToolbar}": Method not found: class
customComponent.onPreRenderToolbar(javax.faces.event.ComponentSystemEvent)
```

The problem is that it initiates the onPreRenderToolbar method on the “someClass”  rather than the toolbar itself (this did not happen for PF 6.2.2 and earlier).

**XHTML:**

```
<h:form id="form" rendered="#{not (param['toolbar'] eq 'false') }">
    <p:menubar id="menuBar" model="#{cc.attrs.toolbar.model}">
       <c:if test="#{not empty cc.attrs.toolbar}" >
           <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener=" 
           {cc.attrs.toolbar.onPreRenderToolbar}"/>
       </c:if> 
    </p:menubar>
</h:form>
```

The Context Menu is inside the "someClass" (which essentially is a form), while the toolbar is outside this component.
Someone have any input/suggestions on what could be changed between these two versions that could cause this issue?

Comment: What is someClass? What is toolbar? Are both attributes of the same custom component? What is the expected type? How do you invoke your custom components? Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Looks like you're missing the hash symbol in `listener="{cc.attrs.toolbar.onPreRenderToolbar}"`